# Finding correct statistical test for my study

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

So I have a study that I have carried out with 40 test subjects. The study consisted of reading two different texts using different methods and answering a number of questions corresponding to each text. Half the population read text $t_1$ using method $m_1$ and $t_2$ using method $m_2$. The other half read text $t_1$ using method $m_2$ and text $t_2$ using method $m_1$.

I'm trying to figure out if there's any inherent difference in difficulty between the two texts, but I can't figure out which statistical test to use. It feels as if a paired t-test is wrong since the same person read the two texts using different methods, but I'm not really sure what else to use.

Answer (score 1):

It's not any kind of t-test because you are not comparing two means.

I think you want a multilevel model with person as a random effect and method and text as fixed effects.

Comment: Don't we want to compare two means? If the results from the two texts have different means, shouldn't that imply that they are of different difficulty if we perform an **unpaired** t-test? As there are just as many who read the two different texts with every method.

Comment: There are really 4 means. T1 with M1, T1 with M2 etc.